# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cos'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to figure out why the above error came up in my code. The program is suppose to use the Newton Raphson Method to find the position of links in a 4 bar linkage given two input parameters.

The error is happening in this line

```
g1 = L1 * np.cos(theta) + L2 * np.cos(alpha) - L3
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import numpy as np

L1=1
L2=1.5 * L1
theta = 40 * np.pi / 180

#initial guesses

L3 = 1.5
alpha = 30 * np.pi / 180
epsilon = 1
n = 0

while epsilon > 0.0001:
    g1 = L1 * np.cos(theta) + L2 * np.cos(alpha) - L3
    dg1dalpha = -L2 * np.sin(alpha)
    dg1dL3 = -1;

    g2 = L1 * np.sin(theta) - L2 * np.sin(alpha)
    dg2dalpha = -L2 * np.cos(alpha);
    dg2dL3 = 0

    J = np.array([[dg1dalpha, dg1dL3], [dg2dalpha, dg2dL3]])

    s = np.array([[alpha], [L3]]) - J/np.array([[g1], [g2]])

    epsilon_alpha = abs(s[0] - alpha)

    epsilon_L3 = abs(s[1] - L3)

    epsilon = max(epsilon_alpha.all, epsilon_L3.all)

    alpha = s[0]

    L3 = s[1]

    n = n + 1

print(n, alpha, L3)
```

Comment: Is there any place where you assign an `np.array(..)` to a variable named `np`?

Comment: The error occurs because after a few iterations, `alpha` ends up being an array with dtype `object`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: ah, good catch!  (The code won't even get through one loop for me because I'm using Python 3 and so the `max` fails-- in 2 it'll just give an answer that I doubt the OP intends.)

Comment: @JustinWhite: Print `alpha` at the start of the loop.  You'll see that it is probably not what you expect it to be.

Comment: I ran it and it failed with  'TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() > builtin_function_or_method()' on line 31 which is "epsilon = max(epsilon_alpha.all, epsilon_L3.all)"

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser it does create an array! But why does alpha become an array I'm setting alpha equal to the first index of s at the end of each loop so shouldn't it just be that number after each time? Thanks

Comment: @TrisNefzger, you are using python3, the OP is using python2

Comment: @TrisNefzger, you do realise you can use parens with print in python2?

Comment: @Justin White  Try printing out s each time through the loop.  I'll bet it's not what you want.

Comment: Can someone explain what I'm looking at                                                    s= [[  1.85083849   2.29325173]
 [-10.61649234   1.5       ]]

s= [[[array([ 1.98227296,  1.95343536]) 1.7138098231972174]
  [array([ 1.81303794,  1.7604074 ]) 2.2932517265367176]]

 [[array([-12.42120598, -12.02523985]) -0.5725860782703323]
  [array([-10.09745674,  -9.374792  ]) 1.5]]]

Comment: Not sure how I can make that look prettier. It's hard to read.

Comment: Add that hard to read comment to your question (as a clearly marked addition or edit).  Then you can format it to easy reading.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with Python3.4. Which Python version do you use? Nevertheless, your problem is in the lines where you assign arrays to`J` and `s`. During the first iteration `alpha` is an integer. But with `s = np.array([[alpha], [L3]]) ...` you assign a 3-dimensional array to `s`. Later on you try to update `alpha` with `alpha = s[0]`. But `s` is an array of shape `(2,2,2)` and thus its 0th element is a 2d-array by itself! Therefore, `s` has this weird shape. There are at least two further errors in your code: it has to be  `epsilon_alpha.all()` same with `epsilon_L3`.

Answer (score 3):

In Python2.7 adding a `print('alpha',alpha)` at the start of the loop produces:

```
('alpha', 0.5235987755982988)
('alpha', array([ 1.85083849,  2.29325173]))
('alpha', array([[array([ 1.98227296,  1.95343536]), 1.7138098231972174],
       [array([ 1.81303794,  1.7604074 ]), 2.2932517265367176]], dtype=object))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack32444132.py", line 17, in <module>
    g1 = L1 * np.cos(theta) + L2 * np.cos(alpha) - L3
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cos'
```

So the error is caused by calling `np.cos(alpha)` where `alpha` is an object array.  `alpha` is `(2,2)`; the 1st column contains length 2 arrays; the 2nd contains floats.

So at some point in the loop you are appending or conconatenating arrays or lists of different length.

```
s = np.array([[alpha], [L3]]) - J/np.array([[g1], [g2]])
alpha = s[0]
```

adding some more prints (before `s`)

```
('J', (2, 2), dtype('float64'))
('alpha', 0.5235987755982988)
('L3', 1.5)
....
('J', (2, 2), dtype('O'))   
('alpha', array([ 1.85083849,  2.29325173]))
('L3', array([-10.61649234,   1.5       ]))
```

In the 2nd loop `J` changes from a 2x2 matrix of floats to a 2x2 of objects.

Python3 raises an error earlier, at the first encounter of the `epsilon = max(epsilon_alpha.all, epsilon_L3.all)` expression.  `epsilon_alpha.all` is a method; `epsilon_alpha.all()` is a boolean.  But even that produces an error when `epsilon_alpha` becomes an array.

OK, this loop runs (`alpha` remains a scalar); it doesn't stop, presumably because `epsilon` does not get small enough; but I'll leave that to you.

```
while epsilon > 0.0001:
    # print('alpha', alpha)
    g1 = L1 * np.cos(theta) + L2 * np.cos(alpha) - L3
    dg1dalpha = -L2 * np.sin(alpha)
    dg1dL3 = -1;

    g2 = L1 * np.sin(theta) - L2 * np.sin(alpha)
    dg2dalpha = -L2 * np.cos(alpha);
    dg2dL3 = 0

    J = np.array([[dg1dalpha, dg1dL3], [dg2dalpha, dg2dL3]])
    print('J', J.shape,J.dtype)  # (2,2) floats
    s = np.array([[alpha], [L3]]) - J/np.array([[g1], [g2]])
    s = s[:,0]  # fudge to turn (2,2) array into a (2,) array

    epsilon_alpha = abs(s[0] - alpha)
    epsilon_L3 = abs(s[1] - L3) 
    epsilon = max(epsilon_alpha, epsilon_L3)
    # max on 2 scalars is ok

    alpha = s[0] # scalar
    L3 = s[1]    # scalar
    n = n + 1
```

The root of the problem is in the

```
 s = np.array([[alpha], [L3]]) - J/np.array([[g1], [g2]])
```

If `alpha` and `L3` are scalars, then `np.array([[alpha], [L3]])` is `(2,1)`.  So is `np.array([[g1], [g2]])`.  But since `J` is (2,2), `s` is also (2,2).  But you've been using `s[0]` and `s[1]`, evidently assuming `s` is `(2,).

```
 s = s[:,0]
```

makes `s` a (2,) so the rest of the code works.  Since `epsilon` does not converge it probably is the wrong fix.

May I stress - when developing `numpy` code, pay close attention to the array shapes.  If the shapes are wrong you'll get errors like this.  In my experience getting the shapes right is 80% of the debugging work.

Comment: Wow, @hpaulj thanks for the detailed post. I need to learn how to do efficient debugging like you just did. I'll keep working on getting the shapes right as you suggested.