# Function defines an unwanted attribute to a numpy array for mysterious reason

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I am trying to build a meshgrid in order to compute an interpolation. I inspire myself from [this example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator.html). My function is the following:

```
def oscillatory_(a,b,d,w=w,c=c):
    x = np.array([a,b,d])
    return np.cos(2*math.pi*w[0,0] + np.sum(c.T*x, axis = 1))
```

Which I call through:

```
data = oscillatory_(*np.meshgrid(a,b,d,indexing='ij', sparse=True))
```

Where

```
a = grid_dim[:,0]
b = grid_dim[:,1]
d = grid_dim[:,2]
```

are just some values taken from grid_dim which is a numpy n-array

When trying to run the code, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in f
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cos'
```

I really don't understand why is he assigning cos as an attribute and not a function, because if I run the function oscillatory outside the *np.meshgrid() everything is ok.

Also, I have played with the toy example from the link below adding a np.cos function and everything works fine. The problem is in my function and I am not able to figure where.

I am doing this in order to compute an interpolation afterwards through:

```
my_interpolating_function = RegularGridInterpolator((a,b,d), data)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated on that one. 
Thank you very much

Comment: If you give `np.cos` an array with object dtype, it iterates through the array, trying to delegate the task to an `cos` method for each item.  I suspect then that you've passed an array of arrays to `cos`.  Examine the`cos` argument for shape and dtype.

Comment: Are you using spyder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'cos'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444132/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-cos)

Answer (score 0):

Making an array from sparse `meshgrid` produces an object dtype array

```
In [448]: I,J=np.meshgrid([0,1,2],[0,1], indexing='ij', sparse=True)                 
In [449]: I                                                                          
Out[449]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
In [450]: J                                                                          
Out[450]: array([[0, 1]])
In [451]: np.array([I, J])                                                           
Out[451]: 
array([array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]]), array([[0, 1]])], dtype=object)
```

With sparse False, you get a valid numeric array:

```
In [452]: I,J=np.meshgrid([0,1,2],[0,1], indexing='ij', sparse=False)                
In [453]: I                                                                          
Out[453]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
In [454]: J                                                                          
Out[454]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
In [455]: np.array([I, J])                                                           
Out[455]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but even with telling sparse = False, which is exactly what I want, I get a tuple problem. I did a post specifically on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807085/python-3d-grid-interpolation-with-scipy-regulargridinterpolator-tuple-index-out